# Process dies after Jsch exits

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I have a shell script that starts tomcat using 'catalina.sh start'. This script runs fine and starts tomcat which stays up even if I exit from my ssh session.

I am trying to invoke this script from Jsch

```
shell = new JSch();
session = shell.getSession(user, host, SSH_DEFAULT_PORT);
session.setConfig(config);
session.setPassword(password);
session.connect();
commandChannel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
commandChannel.setCommand(command);
commandChannel.setPty(true);
commandChannel.connect();
```

This calls my script fine and tomcat starts up, but as soon as the process exits, tomcat is given a shutdown signal and it shuts down. I tried to use setDaemonThread without success. Any idea why this is happening?

UPDATE: The script also does a couple of sudo operations unrelated to starting tomcat so it needs tty. The user is setup in sudoers so as not to require a password, so no prompt is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you shouldn't allocate a pty to the command for the command to run in the background and not be attached to a terminal. What happens if you do `commandChannel.setPty(false)` instead?

EDIT: are you actually running sudo and supplying a password in the script? Shouldn't you run it as root instead? 
If using sudo is what you want, after running the commands detach them from the terminal using `disown` or `nohup` ([explanation](http://www.basicallytech.com/blog/index.php?url=archives/70-Shell-stuff-job-control-and-screen.html&serendipity%5bcview%5d=linear#bg_nohup))

Comment: I get 'sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo' , that's why I added it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Does this problem happen only when your session exits immediately? It sounds like the command you run spawns a separate process. Perhaps you are not giving enough time for the other process to be spawned.

What happens if you execute your command with [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)?